# Creating shape of pizza using arc Android

Tags: android, canvas

I am relatively new to canvas . I want to achieve this kind of view using canvas in android . I have tried 2 approaches

1.) Created a custom view class and called that view from xml 6 times changing angles. All these custom views were overlapping and provieded with margins to create the look.

2.) Created a view class with all 6 arcs placed next to each other. In this approach, I am not able to provide margin between 2 pieces.

Moreover , how to write text on individual piece. If I use drawTextOnPath, text is written but the angle of text is obviously in accordance to the path. How to write horizontal text as shown in picture?

Any kind of guidance will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use third party libraries in this case, because simple drawing "pie view" requires a lot of implementation. See for example this [lib](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) .

This library has a lot of useful controls, not only pie chart.